# Dictionary add if doesn't exist

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have a data set with duplicates and want to loop through the data and add if the key doesn't exist.

```
Dim SSBIds As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim key As Variant
For i = 2 To endSSB
    For Each key In SSBIds
        If Not SSBIds.Exists(key) Then
            SSBIds.Add SSB.Cells(i, 1).Value2, i
        End If
    Next
Next i
```

endSSB is just the last row of the data set. I just keep staring at this and can't figure out why it won't work.

Comment: maybe sharing your data and where you trying to use the `Dictionary` can help us a bit

Comment: I can't share the data. However, it's only column A and all random 9 digit identifiers that could contain letters and numbers. It's around 4000 rows with ~1100 unique identifiers. The key is the only part that is important to me, the value is just a placeholder.

Comment: what is not working ? are you getting an error ? what is the result you are getting ?

Comment: The dictionary isn't loading any keys at all.

Comment: what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Loop through column A of the SSB sheet and if the value isn't already in the dictionary, add it.

Comment: see my answer, where I assume `SSB` is a valid worksheet reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
Dim SSBIds As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

you are defining a brand new `Dictionary`, and then with:

```
For Each key In SSBIds
```

you are trying to loop through its keys, which however are empty...

Maybe you're after this

```
Dim SSBIds As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Long
With SSB
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Not SSBIds.Exists(.Cells(i, 1).Value2) Then SSBIds.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value2, i
    Next
End With
```

Comment: That works, thank you! Would you mind pointing out where my logic/code was flawed?

Comment: you are welcome, see edited answer for the required explanation