# Draw 30 random numbers that aren't duplicates between 1-1000

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, random, duplicates

I want to make a lottery in Excel where I draw approximately 30 random numbers between 1-1000 and where the 30 numbers aren't duplicates.

How do I check if the array has duplicates and run the code again if so.

The below VBA code generates random numbers/winners.

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim MIN, MAX, OUT, i
    Static a, n, z
    MIN = Array(1, 1, 1, 1): MAX = Array(10, 10, 10, 10): OUT = Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
    z = UBound(MIN)
    If Not IsArray(n) Then ReDim a(z): ReDim n(z)
    For i = 0 To z
        If n(i) = 0 Then Reset a(i), n(i), MIN(i), MAX(i)
        Range(OUT(i)) = a(i)(n(i)): n(i) = n(i) - 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Reset(a, n, MIN, MAX)
    Dim i, j
    Randomize: n = MAX - MIN + 1: ReDim a(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        j = Rnd * (i - 1) + 1: a(i) = a(j): a(j) = i - 1 + MIN
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to keep using VBA however, there is a dictionary Object you can use,[something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448236/19353309).

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use VBA, `Evaluate` and a formula:

```
Sub writeRandomNumbers(rgTarget As Range)
rgTarget.Resize(30).Value = Evaluate("=TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(1000),RANDARRAY(1000)),30)")
End Sub
```

You can call this sub like this:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
writeRandomNumbers Range(1, 1)
End Sub
```

But obviously you could use the formula itself on the sheet as well.
But then it will update any time another formula is calculated.

Using the VBA code writes the random **values** to the sheet whenever the user clicks the button.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response! I dosen't get it to work... Ive tried both in VBA and directly in the sheet!?

Comment: Do you have `TAKE` as a formula when you type `=` into a cell?

Comment: I do not. I use Excel in Swedish, and I do have "Ta" which is translated to "Take" and returns array, rows,[columns].

Comment: That sounds like Excel 365. What error do you get when using the VBA code?

Comment: Dosen't get any error... Maybe I am doing it wrong? Where should the first code go? Directly to "ThisWorkbook" or to "Sheet 1"?

Comment: Best into a normal module ... you can then call it e.g. via a test routine: select a cell on any sheet, and call `writeRandomNumbers Selection`

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea with the formula that Ike provided (and upvoted it, it is working for me).
The following solution works also with older versions of Excel. It uses a `Collection` that holds the list of all lottery tickets. In the example, it will be filled with numbers from 1 to 1000, but you can fill it with whatever you want. The basic idea is to create a random index into that collection, write the value of the collection member and remove that entry from the collection.

```
Sub writeRandomNumbers(tickets As Collection, rgTarget As Range, drawCount As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To drawCount
        Dim ticketIndex As Long
        ticketIndex = Int(Rnd * tickets.Count) + 1
        rgTarget.Offset(i - 1, 0) = tickets(ticketIndex)
        tickets.Remove ticketIndex              ' Remove this ticket
        If tickets.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub      ' No more tickets
    Next
End Sub
```

For testing, the Collection can be filled with this small routine:

```
Function createTickets() As Collection
    ' This is only an example, creating tickets from 1 to 1000
    ' You can fill the collection which whatever you want (eg Names from a Range).
    Set createTickets = New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 1000
        createTickets.Add i, CStr(i)
    Next
End Function
```

And this is my test routine:

```
Sub test()
    Dim tickets As Collection
    Set tickets = createTickets
    writeRandomNumbers tickets, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), 30
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the *key* is to avoid *DUPLICATES* and to generate unique sequences. Try to follow your structure,

```vb
`// removed randomisation, added generator
`//
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const numRng As Integer = 4
    Static a(1 To numRng) As Collection
    Static n(1 To numRng) As Integer
    Dim MIN As Variant, MAX As Variant, OUT As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    MIN = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
    MAX = Array(10, 10, 10, 10)
    OUT = Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
    
    For i = 1 To numRng
        If n(i) = 0 Then
            Set a(i) = New Collection
            GenSeq a(i), MIN(i - 1), MAX(i - 1)
            n(i) = a(i).Count
        End If
        Range(OUT(i - 1)).Value = a(i)(n(i))
        n(i) = n(i) - 1
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub GenSeq(ByRef sequence As Collection, ByVal MIN As Integer, ByVal MAX As Integer)
    Dim numPool As Object
    Dim num As Variant
    Set numPool = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For num = MINValue To MAXValue
        numPool(num) = True
    Next num
    
    While numPool.Count > 0
        num = numPool.Keys()(Int((numPool.Count) * Rnd))
        sequence.Add num
        numPool.Remove num
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Still gives duplicates tho, and I am not the guy to understands why!... :)

Comment: @OskarPrenk do you get any _error code_ in your _Run_? I "guess" is down to the function doesn't seem to be functioning ;), see if you have any error or I can take another look in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set up 40 or so rows with

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,1000)
```

then use =unique(rangehere) to eliminate any duplicates, and take first 30 items